# .hide and .show in Edge

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some divs that can be expanded with a "read more" link. If the content inside the div is below a certain height, "read more" should not appear.
The code I have using .show and .hide works in Chrome and Firefox, but not Edge.

I could not find why it is not working in edge or a workaround.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.text').each(function(element,index){
        if($(this)[0].scrollHeight>$(this).height()){
            $(this).next().show()
        }else{
            $(this).next().hide()
        }
    })
});
function changeheight(obj) {
        var fullHeight = $(obj).parent().prev().get(0).scrollHeight
        var readmore = $(obj);
        if (readmore.text() == '[+]Read more') {
            readmore.text("[-]Read less");
            $(obj).parent().prev().data('oldHeight',$(obj).parent().prev().height())
            $(obj).parent().prev().animate({'max-height':fullHeight},750)
        } else {
            readmore.text("[+]Read more");
           $(obj).parent().prev().animate({'max-height':$(obj).parent().prev().data('oldHeight')},750)
           $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(obj).parent().prev().offset().top - 70}, 750);
        }
    };
```

```css
.text {
    overflow:hidden;
}
.height {
    max-height:500px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<div class="text height" style="background-color:green;">                 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ultricies ante a elit blandit, sit amet semper eros mattis. In faucibus vel libero nec faucibus. In et tellus massa. Donec orci nulla, egestas sit amet molestie a, porttitor id leo. Cras elit odio, volutpat convallis sagittis quis, convallis nec est. Duis lobortis pellentesque sem. Aliquam finibus fermentum erat et placerat. Proin non auctor nibh. Morbi sed lectus nec felis volutpat interdum. Maecenas vel neque velit. Nullam venenatis nulla quis malesuada scelerisque.
</div>
<div class="link">                
<a id="readmore" href="javascript:void();" onclick="changeheight(this)">[+]Read more</a>
</div> 
</div>
```

Check this fiddle for full code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jc640rqz/)

I expect [+]Read more to disappear in edge. Does anyone have a workaround or better solution to this problem?

Comment: It is working in my edge

Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0

Comment: I'm on 44.17763.1.0 but the green box still shows read more[+] for me on the fiddle. My edge is all default settings